# If we have a specific matrix A, how can we find X such that AX = Another specific matrix.

Tags: matrices

The specific question is if A= $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 0\\ 0 & 2 & 3\\ 1& 2 & -1\end{bmatrix}$

Solve for X such that AX= $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&6\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$

At first I thought X would just be the product of the elementary matrices that would change A to AX, but that'd only apply if we were solving for XA I realized.

Comment: Hint: Is $A$ invertible?

Comment: It is, and I've found the inverse, but I can't quite see what to do with it.

Comment: You are trying to find $X$ such that $AX=B$ where $B$ is the matrix in your second equation.  Try to solve for $X$, i.e. get $X$ on one side of the equation by itself.  Could you do something to both sides of this equation that would accomplish that?

Comment: I've got it now, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

The determinant of $A$ is equal to $-2$

**Further Hint:**

Since $\det(A)\neq 0$ that implies that $A$ is invertible.

**Final Hint:**

Knowing that $A^{-1}$ exists, we can use it to change our equation.

> By taking $AX=C$ and left multiplying by $A^{-1}$ nice things happen.

Comment: Although you're probably right, my professor has specifically said he wants to avoid the usage of determinants at this point in the course. So I have no idea how to use it or even what it is, and I think he expects us to solve without it.

Comment: Even without the use of determinants, it should be clear from other theorems that $A$ is invertible.  You could just as easily have proven that $A^{-1}$ exists by a row-reduction argument or a column-reduction argument, or by showing that the kernel is trivial.  Being asked this type of question, I would expect you should know how to calculate the inverse of a matrix.  It just so happens that I find it easiest to check if a matrix is invertible by calculating the determinant, but that is not to say it is the only way to do so.

Comment: I can see that it's invertible, and can find the inverse but I don't know what I'd do with it.

Comment: @Zein Remember that if $A=B$ then $CA=CB$.  That is to say, given an equality, you can left-multiply by something and it will remain an equality.  Now, what happens if you left-multiply by $A^{-1}$?  You have $AX=C$, so...

Comment: I'm really surprised I forgot about this. Thanks. I'd be multiplying both sides by the inverse to find X right?

Comment: Indeed.  Remember though, if you multiply on the *left* on one side, you have to multiply on the *left* on the other side as well.  Matrices aren't like real numbers in that multiplication is not commutative (it is not true in general that $AB=BA$).